# Datagrid bind in wpf with one static column and rest dynamic

Tags: wpf, dataset

I am working on WPF where i have to bind datagrid.I try my best to explain my problem if any doubt then please ask.

I am able to bind datagrid by using following code :

XAML view :

```
 <DataGrid Height="257" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="20,12,0,0" Name="dataGrid1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="Auto"></DataGrid>
```

CS view :

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select staticcolumn,column1,column2,column3,column4 from TBL_SENSORS", connection);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "SensorZones");
```

dataGrid1.ItemsSource = dataset.Tables[0].DefaultView;
  ataGrid1.DataContext = dataset.Tables[0];

this code give me a grid with default column names passed from database.

But problem is that in my application i have one combobox from where i have to select column names like column1,column2.On the bases of this selection i have to bind datagrid with these columns only but in all cases i want my staticcolumn is present with modified name Date Recorded and rest selected column with default name.

Thanks

Comment: Why are you using data adapters? are you targeting an older version of c#?

Comment: hi @ExitMusic,this is only for test thats why i am using this.Do you have any idea for this solution ?

Comment: did it work the way you wanted it to?

Comment: no not exactly but i got one idea and had done this,If possible i will add my code also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I would much rather use [linq](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CEMQFjAB&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397926.aspx&ei=mmJwT-HpEsrRhAe_3sSNBw&usg=AFQjCNH7z5Y8dhdHAlNmZENscNwjC1Vykg&sig2=c7OsOt2F8jQpKCHQL6PM2g)

However, what you need to do is have a seperate query based off of each item in the combobox.

Something like :

```
public string SelectedComboboxItem
{
    get
    {
          return _selectedComboboxItem;
    } 
    set
    {
         _selectedComboboxItem = value;
         OnPropertyChanged(SelectedComboboxItem);

         SqlDataAdapter da;
         select (_selectedComboboxItem)
         {
               case "Column 1":
                   da = new SqlDataAdapter("select staticcolumn,column from TBL_SENSORS", connection);


               case "Column 2":
                   da = new SqlDataAdapter("select staticcolumn,column2 from TBL_SENSORS", connection);


          //All the other queries go here

         }

         DataSet ds = new DataSet();
         da.Fill(ds, "SensorZones");

         dataGrid1.ItemsSource = dataset.Tables[0].DefaultView; 
         dataGrid1.DataContext = dataset.Tables[0];
    }
}
```

So you bind your combobox's selected item to this property (you need to implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx)) and then you should have a different datasource for each selection. Unfortunately this should reset the datagrid, so I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for.

Alternatively you could just create a converter and bind the Combobox's selecteditem to the columns' visibility property if you just want to make the columns invisible.